# Clear ZedGraph Data

Tags: c#, charts, zedgraph

I am using ZedGraph on a windows form to display bar chart. Following code executes when user click on a button.

```
zg1.GraphPane.AddBar("Series", null, y, Color.Red);
```

It adds an extra bar every time user click on button. I am looking for a way to reset or clear  data already in chart.

How can i do that????

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
zg1.GraphPane.CurveList.Clear();
zg1.GraphPane.GraphObjList.Clear();
```

Comment: To redraw the graph you may also need to call `zg1.Invalidate()`

Comment: Why are `CurveList` and `GraphObjList` both cleared? How would it work if I tried `zg1.GraphPane.Points = null;` or `zg1.GraphPane.Points = newPointPairList;` ? Understanding this would help me more than trial and error on my end.

Answer (score 1):

don't forget to give 
zg1.Refresh()
if never see the result if you don't refresh.

Comment: This does not answer the question. A comment at best, but something I think the OP is already aware of anyway

Answer (score 0):

No Need to clear anything, the think you need to put at the end of the code after generating the graph is *zg1.Refresh()*